# mlflow search_model_versions pagination not working

Tags: python, machine-learning, mlflow

It looks like the `.search_model_versions()` pagination mechanism has a bug

**Examples:**

Lets say that you have 100 models in MLFlow registry,

**Example 1 [NOT WORKING AS EXPECTED]:**`.search_model_versions()`:

```
from mlflow import MlflowClient

# Case 1 - max_results higher than then register models
>>> client = MlflowClient()
>>>token = client.search_model_versions(max_results=1000).token
>>> print(token)
''

# Case 2 - max_results lower than register models
>>> client = MlflowClient()
>>>token = client.search_model_versions(max_results=1).token
>>> print(token)
''
```

**Example 2 [WORKING CORRECTLY!]** `.search_registered_models()`:

```
from mlflow import MlflowClient

# Case 1 - max_results higher than then register models
>>> client = MlflowClient()
>>>token = client.search_registered_models(max_results=1000).token
>>> print(token)
''

# Case 2 - max_results lower than register models
>>> client = MlflowClient()
>>>token = client.search_registered_models(max_results=1).token
>>> print(token)
'Cghioowcxmw....'
```

***NOTE:** I use `mlflow==2.2.2` client and the server is a managed MLFlow server in Databricks*